# When textbox input a value with decimal, display the same value on the second textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way to do this? When I input a value with a decimal, my 2nd textbox will do the copy without comma and copy the decimal value. How can I make this work? I provided my JS fiddle and codes below. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```js
function updateTextView(_obj) {
  var num = getNumber(_obj.val());
  if (num == 0) {
    _obj.val('');
    $("#textbox2").val('');
  } else {
    $("#textbox2").val(num);
    _obj.val(num.toLocaleString());
  }
}



function getNumber(_str) {
  var arr = _str.split('');
  var out = new Array();
  for (var cnt = 0; cnt < arr.length; cnt++) {
    if (isNaN(arr[cnt]) == false) {
      out.push(arr[cnt]);
    }
  }
  return Number(out.join(''));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#textbox1').on('keyup', function() {
    updateTextView($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Amount" />
<input type="text" value="" id="textbox2" name="amount" />
```

Comment: please share some eg of input and output expected

Comment: https://prnt.sc/17uarrh

the expected output will be the decimal point on the first text box will also appear on the second text box.

Comment: Set the textboxes' values to the same value. Currently you're setting `#textbox2` to `num` and `#textbox1` to `num.toLocaleString()`. Set them both to the value you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `replaceAll` function for `','`

```js
function updateTextView(_obj) {
            var num = getNumber(_obj.val());
            if (num == 0) {
                _obj.val('');
                $("#textbox2").val('');
            } else {
                $("#textbox2").val(num);
                _obj.val(num.toLocaleString());
            }
        }



        function getNumber(_str) {
            var out = _str.replaceAll(",", "")
            return Number(out);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#textbox1').on('blur', function () {
                updateTextView($(this));
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <input type="text" value="" id="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Amount" />
    <input type="text" value="" id="textbox2" name="amount" />
```

Comment: @ jeron I updated my answer to have comma separation value for first text box and for the second one remove all comma and set as a value. this action called on blur of first text box

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you very much for this. So the replaceAll function will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job that too without JQuery. You can try learning Vanilla JavaScript properly on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). I hope you like it. :)

```js
function updateTextView(_obj) {
   var num = _obj.value;
   if (parseFloat(num) == 0) {
     num = ''
   }
   document.getElementById("textbox2").value = num;
} 
    
    
    
    function getNumber(_str){
        var arr = _str.split('');
        var out = new Array();
        for(var cnt=0;cnt<arr.length;cnt++){
            if(isNaN(arr[cnt])==false){
                out.push(arr[cnt]);
            }
       }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="updateTextView(this)" type="text" value="" id="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Amount"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="textbox2" name="amount"/>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE :** Only use libraries when necessary, try not to use libraries for things that can be accomplished with Pure JS.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Btw, I was thinking if it is possible to add comma on the first text box when inputting value in thousands?

Comment: @@Jeron Use `num = (num.match(/.{1,3}/g)).join(",");` before `document.getElementById("textbox2").value = num;`. The code basically splits the text into an array at every third item and then joins them with the separator as a comma.